# Eclipse rcp 4 app export missing class files in the jar

Tags: jar, export, eclipse-rcp, .class-file

I have a RCP 4 app with many plugin projects. The app runs well in IDE but when I run it after exported, some exceptions was throw (ClassNotFoundException).

I investigated then see that it's because of some classes had not yet been exported to the jar files. I don't know why? The configurations in MANIFEST.MF, plugin.xml, build.properties are same but some can export the class to jar file, some not.

Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Update: build.properties file

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               item_editor.e4xmi,\
               plugin.xml
```

Update: MANIFEST.MF file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Item_editor
Bundle-SymbolicName: xxx;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: xxx
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench,
 org.eclipse.osgi.services,
 org.eclipse.jface,
 org.eclipse.e4.core.services,
 xxx,
 xxx,
 org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,
 org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts,
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.di,
 xxx;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions;bundle-version="0.15.0",
 xxx,
 xxx,
 xxx
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Import-Package: javax.inject;version="1.0.0"
Export-Package: xxx,
 xxx,
 xxx,
 xxx,
 xxx;x-internal:=true,
 xxx
```

Comment: This is usually missing entries in the build.properties or MANIFEST.MF. Show us the build.properties and the MANIFEST.MF for a plugin which has the problem.

Comment: @greg-449: I have updated them in the question. Thanks!

Comment: And what are the classes it can't find in this plugin? Are they in the Export-Package list? Are they in the main code or some additional jars?

Comment: It print out that ClassNotFoundException because of the missing class cannot be found by the plugin. The class code is in the plugin but in the jar file of the plugin in, there are no class files (all).

Comment: If you are using Eclipse 'Export Product' check if there is a 'logs.zip' file in the build directory containing build errrors.

Comment: Yes, this is a glue: it reports that there is a type cannot be resolved. This type is in another plugin (exiting a .class) B. B also in the `Require-Bundle:` of current plugin. B also export the package contain the type (in Runtime tab). Thank you very much @greg-449!

Answer (score 1):

I was just facing this issue for couple of days! it was really annoying. here is what we did for our project to start copying the .class files into the package:

**Our problem:** None of the project classes (our classes) are copied inside the exported jar when it is exporting the project.

- In the eclipse, we open the `.project` file we have for the build. It will open it in the editor section.
- In the `content` menu, we click on our own Module entry (we named it XXX_BCC) and it opens it in a sperate editor.
- Then we need to go to the `build` tab as you can see in the picture below.
- Add our `bin` (it is the output folder specified for our .class files) to the `.` classpath!
  [image]
- Under `Runtime Information`, When we were opening it before the change, it was only `src/`, you can press `Add Folder..` and add the `bin/` there. It will add the content of the `bin` folder to the root of the classpath in the exported JAR file.
- We did the export again and our class files were there and we did not receive that exception again.
- Here is the `build.properties` file after the change:
  [image]

-Below is the content of our JAR file after the change and export again. Please notice our packages like   `_bcc` and `YYYY` in the JAR content. They are our classes that were missed before.

[image]

Comment: Why would `bin/` be both a `source` and `output`?